# How to get nested ordered list have different style-type at different levels using css counters?

Tags: html, css, sass, styling

What I want is that a ordered list should have numbers as style-type for first level alphabets for second level and roman numbers for third level and the loop should repeat after the third level for eg. for forth level again number fifth level alphabets and so on...

I am able to achieve it till the third level. How can I loop again?
My code:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: l1;
  }
  
  /* Level 1 */
  ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: l1;
    content: counter(l1, decimal) ". ";
  }
  
  /* Level 2 */
  ol ol {
    counter-reset: l2;
  }
  
  ol ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: l2;
    content: counter(l2, lower-alpha) ". ";
  }
  
  /* Level 3 */
  ol ol ol {
    counter-reset: l3;
  }
  
  ol ol ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: l3;
    content: counter(l3, lower-roman) ". ";
  }
```

Comment: you need to use counters with an s too   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters . to restart/reset, use counter-reset ;)